# Export / unintern and symbol access

Tags: common-lisp

In the following example, I'm getting an error:

```
These symbols are not accessible in the COMMON-LISP-USER package:
  (FOO::BAR)
```

yet,

```
LS-USER> (describe 'foo::bar)
FOO::BAR
  [symbol]
; No value
```

Here's what how I got there:

```
CL-USER> (make-package "FOO" :use '())
#<PACKAGE "FOO">
CL-USER> (intern "BAR" *)
FOO::BAR
NIL
CL-USER> (export (find-symbol "BAR" (find-package "FOO")))
```

Now I understand what the error means and what I'm curious about is: "Is this behaviour correct [according to the spec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_export.htm)?". I'm using SBCL.

I can see why it's not accessible via `foo:bar` (it's not exported). However since `export` is given both the symbol and the package, why can't it access this symbol and export it?  I'm seeing similar things with `unintern`.

A close read says "**export** makes one or more symbols that are accessible in *package* ...".  It doesnt' say it has to be accessible in the current package (`*package*`).

It seems to me that export has all the information it needs to perform the export, but the only way this seems to work is with `(export 'foo::bar (find-package "FOO"))`.  Perhaps it's an underspecified area and this is just what SBCL has choosen to do?

Comment: As the spec says, the optional `package` parameter defaults to the current package. You have to give it explicitly (like in your last example) if you want to use another package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely correct behaviour: anything else would be nonconformant. `(export s)` will try to export the symbols designated by `s` from the current package (the default for the optional second argument of `export`), which is  `CL-USER` in your case.  To do that those symbols must already be accessible in the current package.  A symbol is accessible in the current package if:

- either it is directly present because

  - it either has the current package as its home package
  - or it has been imported into it from some other package,
- or it is accessible by inheritance due to the current package using some other package.

In the final case it will first be imported and then exported.

None of these things is true in your case.  The symbol you are designating, which is `FOO::BAR` since symbols designate themselves, is not accessible in the `CL-USER` package at all.

See [the spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_export.htm)